# criteria on SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a named range (Phase) and it has a continuous set with numbers such as 10.00, 10.06, 13.10, 13.11, 14.10.1, 14.10.2, 14.11.1, 14.13.3, etc. I have another named range (Unbilled) which is the same length as Phase, and has dollar values assigned to each phase.

I'm trying to use the =SUMIF function to add all of the 10's, 13's, 14's, etc. However, with the second argument in the function (criteria), I don't know how to say that 'just add the 10's, 13's, etc.' I have created a column with the numbers 10, 13, 14 etc. and was then trying to refer to that as my criteria. However, it doesn't find 10 in the Phase range, only 10.00 or 10.06, so it doesn't sum those.

The function in AB2 right now is =SUMIF(Phase,AA2,Unbilled). How do I get it to add all of the 10's together, then all the 13's, then all the 14's etc?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with text, not actual numbers, you can use a wildcard:

```
=SUMIF(Phase,AA2&"*",Unbilled)
```